# Erro ao habilitar APC em ambiente local, utilizando wamp 2.5, PHP 5.5.12, Apache 2.4.9 no windows 10

Tags: php, apache, wamp, apc

Já baixei várias DLLs porém não consigo habilitar esta extensão, estou trabalhando em uma aplicação em que por N motivos não posso abrir mão disso, normalmente ele me dá a seguinte warning:

[image: Warning ao iniciar o wamp.]

Tentando utilizar a esta versão do APC: php_apc-3.1.11-svn20120501-5.4-VC9-x64
Obtive a seguinte warning:

[image: Outra warning ao startar o apache]

Qual é a versão exata que preciso utilizar? se possível já com link pra download...

Ou caso a solução seja outra, estou a todo ouvidos.

Comment: Seu php é 32 ou 64bits? e a extensão?

Comment: 64bits, ambos...

Comment: Baixa a versão 64 bits eu ja obtive esse problema

Comment: Eu já fiz isso, e não deu certo, por isso recorri ao SO

Comment: @KennyRafael de fato você tem que pegar versão compatível do apc e do PHP (ou recompilar). Normalmente o APC é mais fácil de encontrar já compilado pra linux.

Comment: @KennyRafael já tentou rodar em modo de compatibilidade o programa?

Comment: tente um desses: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apcu/

Comment: Você vai notar que tem sigas nos nomes como VC11, VC14, NTS.  O x64 é óbvio, trata-se de 64bits. Procure os de 64bits cujo Visual Compiler (VC) seja compatível com a versão que o PHP instalado foi compilado. Note também que deve ser compatível com NTS (non thread safe). Caso a versão do PHP for também NTS. As vezes terá que fazer um downgrade ou upgrade na versão do PHP para que encaixe numa versão disponível do APC ou APCu.